# Issue changing table row selection color

Tags: javafx-8

Is there a way to modify the row selection color for a specific table?

Right now I have a standard row selection style defined in the style-sheet and applies to all the tables throughout the application.

```
.table-row-cell:selected {
  -fx-background-color: #777777;
}
```

However, I have a requirement for one of the tables to display a different highlight color on row select. I had been trying the below but obviously it isn’t working.

In my style-sheet:

```
 #lightHighlightTable .table-view .table-row-cell:selected {
  -fx-background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
```

In my code:

```
recordsTable.setId("lightHighlightTable");
```

Is there something that I am doing wrong in the above? Any hint on how to achieve this is highly appreciated.

I am using JDK 1.8 b20.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work, since the `.table-row-cell` style class is applied to`TableRow`, not to `TableView`:

```
#lightHighlightTable .table-row-cell:selected {
    -fx-background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working too! I have tried applying this id to both the tableView and the row with no luck. I will see if I can build a sample table and if it works. Thanks.

Comment: I've double checked it, and it's working for me. If you have all the tableViews with selection in darkgray (not blue) it means you're loading the css correctly. And if you have one tableView with `setId("lightHighlightTable")` this one should have row selection in lightgray. If this is not the case, try to show the relevant parts of the code affected.

Comment: It wasn't working :(. However, I came up with a not so good solution for the time being adding a listener in my rowFactory. 'tableRow.selectedProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) -> {
                    if (newValue) {
                        tableRow.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #BBBBBB");
                    } else {
                        tableRow.setStyle(null);
                    }
                });'

Comment: As I said before, I can't help you anymore if you don't show the relevant code, sorry.

Comment: Sorry for the previous response <<It wasn't working>>. Pressed ENTER before completing my comment and it posted. Thanks again.

Comment: Ok, no worries. I'm glad it's working for you this way, thought as you said it's not the best solution. Check the code again, sure you'll make it work with css.